# Does costum code in the root folder get lost when wordpress is updated?

Tags: css, javascript

I have added costum JS and CSS in the root folder of the WordPress installation.

If I update Wordpress, does this costum code get lost? See picture: `smardigo` is my webspace root folder and in the folder `costum` is my costum js and css.

[image]

Comment: If you have custom CSS and JS that you're using with WordPress, they should be in your theme or a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, WordPress won't overwrite or delete files in your custom folder. The only places that are normally overwritten in a Core update are Core files themselves, like the ones inside `wp-admin` and `wp-includes`.